# Signing Applications for Android Market

Tags: certificate, google-play

Do I need to purchase a code certificate for apps submitted to the Android Market, or self-signed ones are sufficient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-signing is enough. But of course you need to pay $25 and become a registered developer to publish applications on the market.

For more info:

Publishing your app on the market: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Signing your app: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 2):

no you can just use the eclipse plugin, is really easy - they provide a GUI where you use click thru and enter data. You do have to pay $25 to create an android publishers account but $25 is nothing compared to high apple costs

Comment: Thank you. I chose the other answer by timing only.